# How to print always in one line with updated variables

Tags: python

I want to update variables every second. I can do that wiht time.sleep(1) using Thread. Also I want to use variables in table (`from terminaltables import AsciiTable`) `sys.stdout.write` is can't achieve that. How can I update variables every seconds and print

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import os, subprocess
from scapy import *
import time
import sys
import threading
import keyboard
from time import gmtime, strftime
import read_config as readConfig
import curses
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

# Available fields for nmcli
fields = ('NAME', 'SSID', 'SSID-HEX', 'BSSID', 'MODE', 'CHAN', 'SIGNAL', 'DEVICE', 'DBUS-PATH')

def nmcliGathering():
    cmd = ['nmcli -f NAME,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
    addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    (out, err) = a

ddr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        name = out.replace('\'', '')

        cmd = ['nmcli -f SSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
        addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        (out, err) = addr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        ssid = out.replace('\'', '')

        cmd = ['nmcli -f BSSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
        addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        (out, err) = addr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        bssid = out.replace('\'', '')

        cmd = ['nmcli -f MODE,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
        addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        (out, err) = addr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        mode = out.replace('\'', '')

        cmd = ['nmcli -f CHAN,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
        addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        (out, err) = addr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        chan = out.replace('\'', '')

        cmd = ['nmcli -f SIGNAL,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
        addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        (out, err) = addr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        signal = out.replace('\'', '')

        cmd = ['nmcli -f DEVICE,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk \'$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}\'']
        addr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        (out, err) = addr.communicate()
        out = str(out)
        out = out.replace('b\'', '')
        out = out.replace('\\n', '')
        device = out.replace('\'', '')

        table_data = [['TIME', 'NAME', 'SSID', 'BSSID', 'MODE', 'CHAN', 'SIGNAL', 'DEVICE'],
        [strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()), name, ssid, bssid, mode, chan, signal, device]]
        table = AsciiTable(table_data)

        print(table.table)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        nmcliGathering()
```

UPDATE:

A simple example of what I want to do

```
import sys, time
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        sys.stdout.write('\r{0}'.format(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

In my code I want to print table.table like i in example code

Comment: Can you give some more details on what you are trying to do? At a glance, if your operation takes more than 1 second to run, then you can't get the result in 1 second and print. Keep in mind with sleep(1), you are effectively pausing the program for 1 second, but this does not take into account the amount of time the program itself takes.

Comment: Sorry. I've added a sample code to better explain it.

Comment: What is stopping you from printing it